# No package aclocal available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to install a package `aclocal` on `Amazon SageMmaker` (which is a requirement for `teseract`) using the command `sudo yum install aclocal`

But it gives me the following error.

`No package aclocal available`

Comment: Can you install automake instead `sudo yum install automake`? `aclocal` is provided by `automake` package on some distributions.

Comment: @durga_sury Thanks a lot for answering, but I installed teseract using the following instructinos successfully:  https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install `tesseract` in SageMaker you can simply follow the instructions here: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#linux